# how to prevent multiple logins zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

I have a website and I want to check if a user is already logged in from another device.
I store a session value in the user table and I need some conditions to prevent that from happening.

I have this code for the log in process:

```
public static function login($request)
{

    if (empty($request)) {
         return false;
    }

    Zend_Session::regenerateId();

    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable();
    $authAdapter->setTableName('ah_users');
    $authAdapter->setCredential($request['password']);
    $authAdapter->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?)');
    $authAdapter->setCredentialColumn('password');
    $authAdapter->setIdentity($request['username']);
    $authAdapter->setIdentityColumn('nname');

    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

    if ($result->isValid()) {
        $authData = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject();
        $user = new Model_AhUsers((array) $authData);

        if(!$user->isActive()) return 3; //if user is activated
        if($authData->role == 'admin' && $authData->payment != 'completed') return 4;
        //here i want to query if user is logged in from another browser / pc device to return 1

        $user->seskey = Zend_Session::getId();
        $user->update();
        self::setLoggedUser($user);
        return 0;
    }

    return 2;
}
```

And also I have these functions but no matter how I combine them it isn't working as it should.

```
public static function isLogged()
{
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    return $auth->hasIdentity();
}

public static function setLoggedUser(Model_AhUsers $user)
{
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $storage = $auth->getStorage();
    $storage->write($user);
}

/**
 * @return Model_AhUsers|null
 */
public static function getLoggedUser()
{
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    return $auth->getIdentity();
}

public function logout()
{
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $auth->clearIdentity();
}
```

Comment: If the user is logged in from another browser/device they will have a separate session for that. You will need to use the db to monitor this I think. Also, your comment for that bit of code says it will return 1, but it returns 0.

Comment: well if i check if the user session from db it's different than the actual session that's created when user login it'll never login the user

Comment: No, you don't store the session ID, just a marker that they are logged in.

Comment: i've tryed that but if user never logout than that'll be a problem

Comment: Store the session_id, and on login, check if the session that goes by that ID is still valid. If it is valid it's because the user tries to login again. Note that this may block users if they did not logout correctly and want to come back.

Comment: Are you sure you're not creating a problem where one doesn't exist? Why is a user being logged in from multiple browsers/machines a problem? I do it on lots of sites as I use different machines during the day.

Comment: ok, your ideeas seems legit but how to make that in zend?

Comment: The easiest way to handle this might be to just destroy any session associated with an identity every time a new session is made. So if a user logs in on his desktop then logs in later on his phone or other device the session from his desktop will be expired and destroyed.